# Does Autonomous Database meet HIPAA requirements?

Tags: oracle, hipaa, oracle-autonomous-db

Can I use Autonomous Data Warehouse and/or Autonomous Transaction Processing if my customer has data that is covered by HIPAA requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Autonomous Database demonstrates its HIPAA fitness through an additional attestation prepared in accordance with AICPA SSAE 18, AT-C sections 205 and 315. For more information about HIPAA refer to [Oracle Cloud HIPAA Assessed Regions and Services here](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/data-regions-hipaa.html).

Comment: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Jon, I fixed the URL :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general comment there is no such thing as "HIPAA Compliant Software" or databases for that matter.  In fact there is no HIPPA compliance or certification process that derives its authority from Government.  Certification is really just "issued" by one organization to another when the first agrees that the other has structures (such as a privacy officer) that are consistent with the legislation.  It offers no protection should there be a breach.